# Neither cURL nor file_get_contents can load certain webpages

Tags: php, php-curl

I am running an IIS 8 / PHP web server and am attempting to write a so-called 'proxy script' as a means of fetching HTTP content and loading it onto an HTTPS page.

Although the script does run successfully (outputting whatever the HTTP page sends) in some cases - for example, Google.com, Amazon.com, etc. - it does not work in fetching my own website and a few others.

Here is the code of `proxy.php`:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];

echo "FETCHING URL<br/>";      // displays this no matter what URL I enter 
$ctx_array = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'timeout' => 10,
    )
);
$ctx = stream_context_create($ctx_array);
$output = file_get_contents($url, false, $output);  // times out for certain requests
echo $output;
```

When I set `$_GET['url']` to `http://www.ucomc.net`, the script fails. With most other URLs, it works fine.

I have checked other answers on here and other places but none of them describe my issue, nor do the solutions offered solve it.

I've seen some suggestions to similar problems that involve changing the user agent, but when I do this it not only does not solve the existing problem but prevents other sites from loading as well. I do not want to rely on third-party proxies (don't trust the free ones/want to deal with their query limit and don't want to pay for the expensive ones)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which will result in an error. Please add the full error message you get to your question. As required by the MCVE, add the URL you are trying to access.

Comment: Is the `$output` argument supposed to be `$ctx`?

Comment: If your own web page were filtering by user agent, I think you would know about it.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work on these websites?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's just a typo on my part.

Comment: @Barmar It times out after the 10 seconds specified in the stream context.

Comment: Run curl - v www.ucomc.net from the command line and let us know the output

Comment: FWIW, your code works fine for me on `http://www.ucomc.net`. Do you have a firewall or antivirus that might be getting on the way?

Comment: @Geremy ```* Rebuilt URL to: www.ucomc.net/
*   Trying 73.65.109.123...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.ucomc.net (73.65.109.123) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.ucomc.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection was reset
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was just a problem with the firewall. Testing it on a PHP sandbox worked fine, so I just had to modify the outgoing connections settings in the server firewall to allow the request through.